# When Congress passed the Equal Rights Amendment, why didn't they include the time limit in the amendment itself?

Tags: united-states, constitution, amendment

The [Equal Rights Amendment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equal_Rights_Amendment) was passed by Congress in 1972 and submitted to the states for ratification. Congress imposed (or tried to impose?) a 7-year time limit on ratification.

There was precedent for such a time limit. Each of the 18th, 20th, 21st, and 22nd Amendments includes a section like this:

> This article shall be inoperative unless it shall have been ratified as an amendment to the Constitution by the legislatures of three-fourths of the several states within seven years from the date of its submission to the states by the Congress.

The 21st says "conventions" rather than "legislatures". At least one other proposed amendment included a similar section.

But the ERA's time limit was in the resolution that introduced it, not in the amendment itself. (I believe this raises some questions about the validity of the deadline, but I'm not asking about that here.)

Apparently [Martha Griffiths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martha_Griffiths) was the author of the resolution.

Why was the time limit written as part of the resolution rather than as part of the amendment itself, as had been done for five previous proposed amendments?

Comment: I wasn't sure whether to post this here or in [history.se], but given the existing tags [politics.se] seemed more appropriate.

Comment: If I read this correctly, putting a time limit like that into the amendment would mean the amendment would cease to apply if it is not ratified by enough states. That might not be a desirable effect for those writing the amendment.

Comment: @quarague once an amendment is adopted, the only way it can cease to apply is by the adoption of another amendment saying so.  New states adopt the entire US constitution, including the amendements, when they are admitted.  They don't vote on each amendment separately.

Comment: Because the amendment doesn't have a time limit - the adoption process is specified to have a time limit.  Why would the amendment itself have a time limit?  "This change to the Constitution expires 7 years after adoption" wouldn't make much sense.

Comment: @quarague The intent in either case would be that the amendment would not go into effect if it's not ratified within 7 years. The question is why the time limit was written into the resolution rather than into the amendment itself.

Comment: @JustMe I was referring to the time limit on ratification. I wasn't suggesting at all that the amendment itself might expire after going into effect. Congress stated a 7-year limit on *ratification*. My question is why that limit was stated in the resolution that introduced the amendment rather than in the amendment itself (as had been done for several other amendments).

Comment: As a note the 27th took 202 years, 7 months, and 12 days to get ratified https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twenty-seventh_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution

Comment: The question cites four other amendments that have this "time limit on ratification" language in the amendment itself. So general comments of the form "Why would anyone ever include such a limit in the amendment? That wouldn't make much sense" don't add anything to the discussion. It is a thing that **has** been done - multiple times - in a process that requires agreement of large numbers of people, so clearly it makes at least some sense to some people. The OP is just asking if there is a specific reason this case was handled differently.

Comment: @Ben Yes, exactly.

Comment: @JustMe A time-limited amendment is not inconceivable; the original Constitution contained a clause explicitly guaranteeing that the international slave trade would be protected until 1808.

Comment: There are four old amendments approved by Congress but still technically pending before state legislatures: the [Congressional apportionment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congressional_Apportionment_Amendment) (1789), [Titles of Nobility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titles_of_Nobility_Amendment) (1810), [Corwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corwin_Amendment) (1861), and [Child Labor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Child_Labor_Amendment) (1924) amendments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*When Congress passed the Equal Rights Amendment, why didn't they include the time limit in the amendment itself?*

The change was not specific to the proposed Equal Rights Amendment.

There was a change in *form* for submitting Joint Resolutions for Constitutional Amendments that occurred between the 22nd (1940) and 23d (1960) amendments, where the "inoperative clause" was removed from the amendment text. To accommodate the seven year limit for ratification, the limit was moved to the preamble (after the resolving clause).

In the 22nd Amendment,

> This Article shall be inoperative unless it shall have been ratified as an amendment to the Constitution by the legislatures of three-fourths of the several states within seven years from the date of its submission to the states by the Congress.

However, with the 23d (24th, 25th, and 26th) amendment there is no "inoperative clause",

> *Resolved by ...* That the following article is hereby proposed as an amendment to the Constitution of the ·united States, which shall be valid to all intents and purposes as part of the Constitution only if ratified by the legislatures of three-fourths of the several States within seven years from the date of its submission by the Congress:

(Images of the Joint Resolutions are available on the Wikipedia articles for the respective amendments.)

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't realized that several other later amendments also included a 7-year ratification time limit in their resolutions. Do you have any information about why this change was made?

Comment: @KeithThompson - No. I would guess that someone finally realized the absurdity of having the "inoperative" statement in a ratified amendment. Finding anything in the Congressional record, if present, would be a daunting task and it may have been decided in committee, thus would not appear in the CR at all. That does not mean that I won't spend some free time looking for the information.